# Is there a difference between using for-each and Contains in joining on a query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, join

Let's say I am doing a join like this below:

```
var query1 = (from ga in this.Context.GroupAddress
    join gpa in this.Context.GroupsProvidersAddresses on ga.GroupAddress_K equals gpa.GroupAddress_K
    where this.TerminatedGroupAddressesKeys.Contains(ga.GroupAddress_K)
            select gpa.ProviderAddress_K).ToList();
```

where `TerminatedGroupAddressesKeys` is a collection of strings that I have and I am using .`Contains`

Is that different from doing a `for-each loop` on `TerminatedGroupAddressesKeys` and saying where `ga.GroupAddress_K == forEachItemInTheLoop`

Comment: yes, contains will be executed on database, for-each will be executed on client side.

Comment: are you using EF? If so, please add tags accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use contains because it will be executed in database and reduce the size of data that will be transferred between client and database. Also using foreach will reduce readability of your code

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. But in case of the result they return, they will be the same? right?

Comment: I don't think so, it's all about the data you have. because of the join there will be many duplication of records and that may make problems when you are filtering with for-each

Comment: How should I know which one should I use then now that results are different ? :(

Comment: So I think I can do a Distinct on the string collection before I do a For-Each on it?

Comment: I think the best way is to test it on sample data and verify that it gives you the desired result. Also you can get help from others to double check it.